# How to Enable CORS in Behance API?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, frontend, behance-api

I am creating an Angular Application, In that, I'm calling a Behance API with Auth_token, But It's Throwing like this Error.

Comment: i don't think there is a lot that you can do in the client side as CORS is enforced by the browser and caused by the API not including access control headers. You can only try to disable CORS check in your browser by either using an extension or by running it with special security disable flags